# How do I convert a light circuit with a single pole switch to use two 3-way switches?

Tags: electrical

I have a box in the hall which includes a 3-way switch (with another switch at the other end of the hall), a single pole switch to the garage lights and a single pole switch to the exterior lights on the garage.  The single pole switch to the garage is wired with a 3 wire plus ground. The white and black wires feed the garage lights from the switch and the red wire feeds the garage ceiling outlets and is hot all the time.

In the garage I would like to add a 3-way switch for the garage lights and another 3-way switch for the exterior garage lights.  In other words I would like to be able to turn on both of those light locations from both the inside hall and the garage as well. I know that I will of course have to replace the existing single pole switches in the hall with 3-way switches and add a junction box in the garage with 2 3-way switches in it.  The thing that I don't know is what wiring connections I need to make.

Can you help?

Comment: Consider putting in a wireless switch, some are now even selfpowered

Answer (score 6):

Since the red wire is already being used for the outlets, you'll need to run a pair of 3 wire cables from the existing switch box to the location in the garage where you want these light switches.

This is what you'll likely have to do:

[image]

Here are some other options:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Image Source](http://www.electrical-online.com)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but circuits #3,  #4 and #5 don't have neutral wires at both switches, they would probably violate modern codes. #1 and #2 are simpler and also more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, the miracles of modern science. You can control your light from multiple locations, and you don't even have to run any additional wiring. All you have to do is install these [LevNet RF™](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/SectionDisplay.jsp?section=37824&minisite=10251) self-powered wireless switches from [Leviton](http://www.leviton.com).

Here's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KeGc5cPX8o&feature=youtu.be) describing how to program the switches.

Comment: -1 Link only answers become useless when the link goes bad and are frequently confused with spam. Be sure to provide context around the link and quote relevant content in case the link goes bad. See [how to answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: @BMitch, this is a quote of a comment about my answer, I answered a different but similar question: "This is a good answer, you should add it to the question that this is a duplicate of. –  Tester101♦ yesterday". Tester101 rep is 69000+. Should I give your answer a -1 because you failed to inform the OP of a much simpler solution?

Comment: I think Tester's edit was all I was looking for, something a person could Google if the link disappeared so that the answer is still useful. -1's can be removed after an edit and I've done so. Also, I completely didn't realize the other answer was from me. Mea culpa, I try to avoid modding in those situations.