# Is it possible to do two 3way switched circuits that share a common power source but the power source and the light wire are in the same box?

Tags: electrical, switch, wire

I'm trying to connect two separate circuits from a single power source using 3way switches. My trouble seems that my wire from my light and my power source are in the same box. Is there a way to do this? I have wired it multiple ways and I keep getting the first switch almost Ike a master that needs to be on for the second circuit to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

You need 14-3 or 12-3 going to each switch from the light/power:

Call the switches L(eft) and R(ight):

Connections@Light:

1. LineInPwr(white) -> Lamp(white)
2. LineInPwr(black) -> L(white tagged black)
3. LineInPwr(gnd) -> tied in common Both L(gnd) and R(gnd)
4. L(black) -> R(black) [traveler]
5. L(red) -> R(red) [traveler]
6. R(white tagged black) -> Lamp(black)

Connections at L switch:

1. L(White tagged black) -> L SW (common)
2. L(Black) -> L SW (brass) [traveler]
3. L(Red) ->  L SW (brass) [traveler]
4. L(gnd) -> L SW (gnd)

Connections at R switch:

1. R(White tagged black) -> R SW (common)
2. R(Black) -> R SW (brass) [traveler]
3. R(Red) -> R SW (brass) [traveler]
4. R(gnd) -> R SW (gnd)

Our own BMitch provided [an answer and diagrams here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/how-do-i-convert-a-light-circuit-with-a-single-pole-switch-to-use-two-3-way-swit/5848#5848) (originally found [here](http://www.electrical-online.com/3-way-switch-diagram-variation-4/)). We differ slightly in wire assignments (mine's better ;-)(why? both switches have the same wire assignments, the magic happens at the light)), but its basically the same.
  [image]