# How do I wire two separate 3-way circuits from the same power source?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, multiway-switch

I have a switch box that has two 3 ways to control two different sets of lights 1 set in the hallway and 1 set in the living room and both of these sets have their own 3 way switch located in different locations but connected by 14/3 wire the power and both sets of lights are brought into the same box all with 14/2 wire.

The problem is I believe I have the wires crossed as when I turn the lights off at either of the different 3-way locations I have no control at the original switch box where the power and lighting wire is located.

How do I supply power to both 3-way circuits from the single power source?

Comment: Similar: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31531/is-it-possible-to-do-two-3way-switched-circuits-that-share-a-common-power-source

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with new information.

Comment: Were these circuits working originally, and if so what did you change? Please post a photograph of the wiring in the junction box, with the various wires labelled.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a typical three-way switch with power to the switch box:

[image]

You'll do just that. With the second circuit, the neutral (white) simply nuts with the others.

For the hots (black), add two pigtails to the source hot and run one to each switch, just as you normally would. Easy peasy.

Comment: +1 But note that the white wire running from the lamp box to the right-hand switch is also hot at times and should be marked *black* with tape or a marker.

Comment: I do not know if that kind of cable is available but here in Europe we use blue as common up to the lamp. Brown supply to the common on  the left hand switch. Two black from the left hand switch to the right hand switch and one black from the right hand common to  the lamp. Black on Brown is incoming hot. Black is possible live. and Blue is always neutral.